# Elegir al azar dos variables de un array

Tags: javascript

Necesito elegir dos variables de una lista tipo array. Hice un codigo pero me parece que es bastante rustico, o no se, no se adecua a las normas que en este punto de mi aprendizaje (novato) son las que deberia seguir. 
Este es el codigo, que funciona perfectamente...

```
function Azar1() {
 let Palabra1 = temas[Math.floor(Math.random() * temas.length)];
 let Palabra2 = temas[Math.floor(Math.random() * temas.length)];
 if ( Palabra1 != Palabra2) {
 alert("las palabras elegidas son :" + Palabra1 + Palabra2);
 }
}
```

donde temas = es el array de palabras, la condicion if es por si la eleccion de las dos palabras es la misma.

Ahora, he visto ejemplos mucho mas complejos, como este ;

```
var arrElm = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

var toTake = 2

var maxToShuffle = Math.min(arrElm.length - 1, toTake)

for (let i = 0; i < maxToShuffle; i++) {
  const toSwap = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (arrElm.length - i))
  ;[arrElm[i], arrElm[toSwap]] = [arrElm[toSwap], arrElm[i]]
}

console.log(arrElm.slice(0, toTake))
```

Que aparentemente funciona, hace lo mismo que hace mi codigo pero en forma mucho mas compleja.

Mi pregunta es, cual es la forma correcta de hacer lo que quiero hacer?

Gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta final objetivo es totalmente basada en opiniones "cual es la forma correcta de hacer lo que quiero hacer?", en stackoverflow las preguntas basadas en opiniones como por ejemplo "cual es el mejor framework o cual deberia usar??" o esta que hicisite normalmente terminan cerradas, puesto que la comunidad no responde a preguntas basadas en opiniones, considera abarcar tu problematica desde un punto de vista no basado en opiniones y editar la pregunta, de lo contrario puede terminar cerrada, tambien te invito a dar un paseo por el [tour] y a leer sobre [ask].

Comment: El "problema" de tu código es que puede darse el caso que elija el mismo elemento dos veces, y entiendo que eso no te interesa. El segundo modifica el array para que no se repita.

¿Es mejor el segundo? Si no quieres repetir valores si, pero ten en cuenta que modifica la posición de los valores del array original.

Lo que hace el segundo es intercambiar con las primeras posiciones del array tantos elementos aleatorios como pidas, y luego solo debes elegir los primeros valores con un slice.

Comment: Esta pregunta está duplicada

Comment: Entiendo, pase por el recorrido y el topic sobre como preguntar. Se que no hay una directiva explicita en mi pregunta, pero creo que esta lejos de la analogia con los frameworks que usas de ejemplo. No creo que google tenga la respuesta a mi pregunta. De alguna forma Arnau Castellvi la respondio, me dijo una diferencia con respecto al metodo que empleo yo y al que cite como ejemplo ; justamente a eso iba, si mi codigo a pesar de ser funcional tendria algun problema como por ej consumo de memoria, escalabilidad a futuro, no se bien como explicarlo porque todavia soy un novato en esto.

Comment: Una forma de cambiar la pregunta o mejorarla seria por ejemplo en vez de poner "cual es la forma correcta de hacer lo que quiero hacer? ", es mas bien decir por ejemplo: "de que manera puedo mejorar la eficiencia de este codigo?", si bien son parecidas no abarcan el mismo punto de vista, para la primera es como preguntar cual es tu color favorito (demasiadas respuestas distintas), pero la segunda es mas especifica, con una problematica directa detras, un objetivo el cual es mejorar la eficiencia del codigo.

Comment: En un ejemplo de la vida real la segunda pregunta seria como preguntar: como se llama este espectro de color?, si bien es un conjunto de colores el espectro solo tiene algunos científicamente definidos, los cuales no son opiniones, son hechos las cuales tienen respuestas definidas y variaciones contables.

Comment: De hecho todo el cuerpo de tu pregunta es totalmente valido, el problema es la pregunta final en si... ya que no hay una unica respuesta al ser basada en opiniones, pero supongo que es bueno hacer excepciones y ayudar a mejorar despues de todo para que existiria esta comunidad si no?, sin embargo creo que no dare una respuesta a la pregunta yo mismo porque estaria siendo desconsiderado con aquellos que borraron sus respuestas debido a considerar esta como una pregunta basada en opiniones,  tal vez las respuestas a esta pregunta no sean bien recibidas por otros miembros de la comunidad.

Comment: Otros miembros de la comunidad mas estrictos, tal vez la pregunta termine cerrada, pero seria buena idea ayudar a aquellos que están aprendiendo, aquellos que decidan crear una buena respuesta a esta pregunta tienen mi apoyo, pese a que esta pueda terminar cerrada.

Comment: Y bueno también hay que mirar si efectivamente es un duplicado a una pregunta que ya existe como lo dice JackNavaRow... si es así buenas noticias ya hay una respuesta a tu pregunta.

Comment: En ppio mi pregunta no estaría duplicada porque mi codigo es "único" y justamente es el eje de la pregunta. Yo creo que a pesar de la "cultura" de stack la pregunta esta bien formulada, la informatica es una ciencia exacta y si bien hay muchas formas de resolver un problema, imagino, en mi "novatez" que existen buenas practicas a la hora de resolver estos problemas. Puedo trazar entonces una analogia entre lo correcto (que es como formule mi pregunta..) y estas "buenas practicas", todo esto porsupuesto desde la optica de la gente que responde aqui, que tiene mas experiencia que yo.

Comment: De hecho... cuando se marca una pregunta como duplicada no quiere decir que la pregunta sea exactamente igual a la tuya... pero si que puede ayudar a resolver tu duda (una pregunta parecida ya se hizo), por lo que... marcar una pregunta como duplicado enrealidad no es malo... es mas, en ciertos casos a mucha gente le ha ayudado una pregunta enlazada como duplicada, normalmente cuando se trata como duplicado es para tener un control sobre qué preguntas ya han sido resueltas para no tener demasiadas respuestas sobre la misma pregunta.